# NFS4 problems on Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I tried installing nfs-common on a Ubuntu 10.04 and on a Ubuntu Server 11.04 machines like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

The `/etc/init.d/nfs-common` script does not get created. Also, the `rpc.idmapd` daemon did not start because of the `/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs` directory missing.

I created the directory in question and `idmapd` now runs, but when I try to mount an NFS4 filesystem, the UID/GIDs do not get mapped correctly (they get mapped to `4294967294:4294967294`), which means that there is a problem with `idmapd`, but the daemon is running and the configuration on both the server and the client is identical (in `/etc/idmapd.conf`).

I read that there was a "solved" bug with `/etc/init.d/nfs-common` not being created, but I am experiencing the issues still on Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu Server 11.04. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the part about `/etc/init.d/nfs-common` not being created. Ubuntu has moved from the traditional `init` to a new system called Upstart. You can manipulate Upstart services using the `service` command, e.g.:

```
$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Comment: the result is the same regardless of whether I am using `service ...` or `/etc/init.d/nfs..`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `4294967294:4294967294` was solved by re-starting the idmap service on both the server and the client.